# Why does Google Chrome not show websites' correct fonts?

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

I just did a fresh install of 11.10, and installed Google Chrome. For many sites it does not display the correct font (it shows the fall-back font instead). Both Chromium and Firefox show fonts correctly. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking under 
Wrench>Settings>Under the Hood-tab>Web Content-Customize Fonts
There you should be able to customize your google chrome fonts